# 'Appending' to Expression<TDelegate> to get a member of a MemberExpression

Tags: .net, lambda

Suppose I have:

```
class Foo {
 public String Bar { get; set; }
}
```

and I have an `Expression<Func<TIn,TOut>>` where `TOut` is constrained to `Foo`. How can I create an `Expression<Func<TIn, String>>` for accessing the `Bar` property?

**Edit**:

The reason I want this is to write an HtmlHelper for ASP.NET MVC for a complex type - e.g. `MyExtension(this HtmlHelper that, Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> expression)` that then calls other HtmlHelper extension methods for properties of the complex type - e.g EditorFor, etc)

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does the first `Expression` do? How does constraining `TOut` help you with anything? What is the relation between the two expressions?

Comment: My code receives an Expression that is of a Func that takes one object and returns another that is of type Foo. I want to create a new Expression that takes the same object, but returns a property of the Foo that the first returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Body` to access the body of the first expression, then `Expression.Property()` to access the property and finally `Expression.Lambda()` to combine it all into a lambda:

```
Expression<Func<TIn, string>> CreateExpression
    (Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> expr)
{
    var barProperty = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar");
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TIn, string>>(
        Expression.Property(expr.Body, barProperty), expr.Parameters);
}
```

If you can use [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) this is somewhat simpler (don' forget `using LinqKit;`):

```
public Expression<Func<TIn, string>> CreateExpression
    (Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> expr)
{
    Expression<Func<TIn, string>> tmp = x => expr.Invoke(x).Bar;
    return tmp.Expand();
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I've removed mycomments to this answer since you edited such that they were no longer relevant.